# Mapping multiple table FKs to a single table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two entities (Student and Location) that I want to form a relationship with a single table (Address).  Below is a sample schema:

**Student**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
(more student specific properties)
public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }
public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
public int SecondaryAddressId { get; set; }
public Address SecondaryAddress { get; set; }
```

**Location**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
(more location specific properties)
public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }
public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
public int MailingAddressId { get; set; }
public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
public int ShippingAddressId { get; set; }
public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
```

**Address**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
...
```

Sample Fluent Configuration

```
HasRequired(x => x.PrimaryAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PrimaryAddressId)
```

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and the fluent API for configuration.  When attempting to fetch data I'm getting the classic 'Discriminator' error.  Can anyone show me the proper way to establish this type of relationship?

Thanks!